# Repeat images in gallery until div is filled out

Tags: jquery

Interested in taking an image gallery (simple flex box) and would like jquery (or alternative?) to repeat images used until the entire gallery is filled out, similar to background image repeat in CSS.

Is there a way to do this that is light on load and simple on implementation? Image sizes are pretty small and would like them to be clickable links as well.

Not finding great information on doing this, or possibly searching for the wrong thing... lots of infinite scroll galleries and slideshows.

Thanks!

---

Edit: From my comments, to clarify:

"If my gallery is 1000px x 1000px, I should be able to fit 16 250px x 250px images, yes? If I only have 12 images, I'd like to automatically fill out that extra space by duplicating 4 of the images.

Where do I start with that? Are there better keywords I need to look for? Everything I find looking for information pulls up something similar to the plugin you linked, resizing images."

Comment: Are you looking for us to code something for you, send you to an offsite resource or is there some related code attempts you can show?

Comment: Just a starting point... search suggests this isn't done very much. Should I abandon the idea? Or is there something simple I've missed completely?

Comment: Maybe look into something like https://masonry.desandro.com/ - otherwise, I'm unsure what you're looking for.

Comment: I'll try to be more clear -- 

If my gallery is 1000px x 1000px, I should be able to fit 16 250px x 250px images, yes? If I only have 12 images, I'd like to automatically fill out that extra space by duplicating 4 of the images.

Where do I start with that? Are there better keywords I need to look for? Everything I find looking for information pulls up something similar to the plugin you linked, resizing images.

Comment: Do the images already exist in your HTML layout or are you adding them with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't made an attempt yet, so I'm not sure what your HTML layout will be or how your image data is defined.

If your images already exist in your HTML layout, you can [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) existing elements as needed to fill your container:

```js
var $container = jQuery('#container');
var $images = jQuery('span', $container);
var total_images = 16;

if ($images.length > 0 && $images.length < total_images) {

  for (var i = $images.length; i < total_images; i++) {

    var image_index = i % $images.length;
    $images.eq(image_index).clone().appendTo($container);

  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: Gray;
}

#container {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container span {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

#container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1080" alt=""></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1081" alt=""></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1082" alt=""></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1083" alt=""></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1084" alt=""></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1075" alt=""></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1076" alt=""></span>
</div>
```

If you're adding images to the page dynamically using JavaScript, like from an AJAX call, you could continue cycling through and inserting images until you've reached the desired number:

```js
var total_images = 16;
var $container = jQuery('#container');
var images = [
  'https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1080',
  'https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1081',
  'https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1082',
  'https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1083',
  'https://picsum.photos/250/250/?image=1084'
];

for (var i = 0; i < total_images; i++) {

  var image_index = i % images.length;

  jQuery('<img>', {
    'src': images[image_index]
  }).wrap('<span>').parent().appendTo($container);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: Gray;
}

#container {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container span {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

#container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for... got stuck on .repeat and missed .clone

Thanks a whole bunch -- this gives me more than enough to get started putting my idea into action. Cheers!